# Как сделать, чтобы межстраничные объявления admob запускались только при входе в приложение?

Tags: admob

Как сделать, чтобы межстраничные объявления admob запускались только при входе в приложение (то есть в одном активити), а после возвращение на тоже самое активити (начальное) оно не запускалось?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@alex11](/users/22359/alex11)](/users/22359/alex11), Вам нужно почитать об [Activity Life Cycle](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/60-urok-23-activity-lifecycle-v-kakih-sostojanijah-mozhet-byt-activity) (ссылка на сайт Start Android), а также о [SharedPreferences](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/73-urok-33-hranenie-dannyh-preferences) (ссылка на тот же сайт).

Я бы сделал так:

*1. Создал SharedPreferences файл.*

*2. Создал в нем переменную isFirstVisit типа boolean, которая бы отвечала за первое посещение приложения пользователем.*

*3. Переменной isFirstVisit присвоил бы по умолчанию значение true (т.е. изначально мы первый раз входим).*

*4. На стартовом Activity задал условие:*

```
if (isFirstVisit == true) {
   // если верно
   // здесь указать нужно будет код для баннера adMob
   // в конце добавить следующее
   isFirstVisit = false; // т.е. мы посетили Activity и сохраняем это в переменной (говорим, что нет, это не первое посещение)
} else {
   // иначе 
   adView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // то есть скрываем рекламный баннер.
}
```

В итоге это будет работать для случая, если Вы зададите переход на первое Activity через intent, а не пропишите доп. кнопку Back с методом onBackPressed.

**UPD 1:**
и дописал бы метод onDestroy() для первой Activity, в котором бы присваивал переменной isFirstVisit значение true. То есть, когда приложение закрывается, активность разрушается. В итоге при новом входе снова будет проверка на первый вход и все по кругу.

Идея простая. Реализовать ее можно. Если я ошибся в каком-то нюансе, то его легко можно будет поправить при тестировании приложения.